# How to setup my PC so that it asks to choose which OS to operate while booting?

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed ubuntu as well as windows 8 in my PC.When i boot my PC,it automatically operates through windows 8.It doesn't asks to choose between available OS.
How do i change that? I want it to ask me which OS to operate while booting?

Comment: Which OS did you install last ? I guess it's Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform mutiboot, please refer the below Microsoft article:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/change-the-default-operating-system-for-startup-multiboot

In order to  choose which operating system to use when you turn on your computer, make sure the Time to display list of operating systems check box is selected, and then click the number of seconds that you want the list of available operating systems displayed before the default operating system starts automatically.